# Inner product of the spherical cap and Gaussian

Tags: measure-concentration, gaussian

Let $d\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\eta \sim N(0,I_d)$ where $N(0,I_d)$ is the gaussian distribution with the covariance matrix of $I_d$. Also, define a spherical cap as follows. Fix $v \in \mathbb{S}^{(d-1)}$ and $\theta \in (0,1)$ where $\mathbb{S}^{(d-1)}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let
$$
C_{v,\theta} = \{x\in \mathbb{S}^{(d-1)}: \langle x,v \rangle \geq \theta \}.
$$

I am interested in an upperbound on the following probability:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\eta \sim N(0,I_d)}\left[ \sup_{x\in C_{v,\theta}} \langle \eta,x \rangle \right].
$$

**Easy Upperbound**

We can write
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{\eta \sim N(0,I_d)}\left[ \sup_{x\in C_{v,\theta}} \langle \eta,x \rangle \right] &\leq \mathbb{E}_{\eta \sim N(0,I_d)}\left[ \sup_{x\in \mathbb{S}^{(d-1)}} \langle \eta,x \rangle \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\eta \sim N(0,I_d)}\left[ \lVert \eta \rVert \right]\\
&\leq \sqrt{d}
\end{align}

How can I improve this naive bound?

Comment: You should give more context and more details, e.g. which parameters you are viewing as fixed and which are big/small.

Comment: @kostya_l: Thanks! I edited the question. An upperbound on the expectation is enough since I can prove concentration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\th\theta\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}$Assume that $d\ge2$. Without loss of generality $v=(1,0,\dots,0)$. Identify then $\eta$ with $X=(X_1,X_2)$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random elements of $\R$ and $\R^{d-1}$, respectively, such that $X_1\sim N(0,1)$ and $X_2\sim N(0,I_{d-1})$.

Then, by simple plane geometry considerations,
$$s_d:=s_d(\th):=\sup_{x\in C_{v,\th}} \langle \eta,x \rangle =\|X\|\,f(R),$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm on $\R^m$ for any $m$,
$$f(R):=1(R>\th)+(\th R+\sqrt{1-\th^2}\,\sqrt{1-R^2})\,1(R\le\th),$$
$$R:=\frac{X_1}{\|X\|}.$$

By (say) the law of large numbers, $\|X\|\to\infty$ and hence $R\to0$ and $f(R)\to\sqrt{1-\th^2}$ in distribution (as $d\to\infty$). So, by dominated convergence, $Ef(R)\to\sqrt{1-\th^2}$. Therefore and because $R$ is independent of $\|X\|$ and because $E\|X\|\sim\sqrt d$, we conclude that
$$Es_d=E\|X\|\,Ef(R)\sim\sqrt{(1-\th^2)d}.$$

---

Moreover, since $R^2$ has the beta distribution with parameters $1/2,(d-1)/2$ and $\|X\|^2$ has the chi square distribution with $d$ degrees of freedom, we get the exact expression for $Es_d$:
$$Es_d \\ =\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg[-2 \theta  \left(1-\theta ^2\right)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}- B_{\theta
   ^2}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{d-1}{2}\right)d  
+B_{\theta
   ^2}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{d-1}{2}\right) \\ 
+(d-1) \sqrt{1-\theta
   ^2} \left(B_{\theta
   ^2}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{d}{2}\right)+B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{d}{2}\right)\right) \\ 
+(d-1)B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{d-1}{2}\right)\bigg],$$
where $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the beta function and $B_\cdot(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the incomplete beta function. These functions are easy to analyze.

---

For $\rho_\th(d):=Es_d/\sqrt{(1-\th^2)d}=Es_d(\th)/\sqrt{(1-\th^2)d}$, here are the graphs
$\{(d,\rho_{0.1}(d))\colon2\le d\le100\}$ (orange) and $\{(d,\rho_{0.9}(d))\colon2\le d\le100\}$ (blue):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Write $\eta=\|\eta\|\hat{\eta}$; then $\hat{\eta}$ is uniformly distributed on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ and independent of $\|\eta\|$. We have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{x\in C_{v,\theta}}(\eta,x)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\|\eta\|\sup_{x\in C_{v,\theta}}(\hat{\eta},x)\right]=\sqrt{d}\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{x\in C_{v,\theta}}(\hat{\eta},x)\right]\stackrel{d\to\infty}{\sim}\sqrt{1-\theta^2}\sqrt{d}.
$$
Indeed, the supremum in the expectation is equal to $1$ when $\hat{\eta}\in C_{v,\theta}$ and to $\cos(\nu(\hat{\eta})-\nu)$ otherwise, where $\nu(\hat{\eta})=\arccos((\hat{\eta},v))$ is the angle between $\hat{\eta}$ and $v$, and $\nu=\arccos\theta$. For large $d$, $\nu(\hat{\eta})$ is concentrated near $\pi/2$, so the cosine in question is concentrated near $\cos(\pi/2-\nu)$. Plugging in effective concentration bounds, you can get a non-asymptotic inequality.

Comment: I think $\theta_\mathrm{MMH}=\cos(\theta_\mathrm{Kostya})$. I just want to add that this looks like it holds for $\theta$ fixed, but we will still have inequalities up to constants in both directions over a domain where $\theta_\mathrm{MMH}\sqrt d$ is uniformly bounded below.

Comment: @PierrePC. I see. you are right. I am not sure I understand your second part of your comment.

Comment: For all $\delta>0$, there exists $C>0$ such that for all $\theta_\mathrm{MMH}\sqrt d\geq\delta$, the expectation is bounded above by $C\sin(\theta_{Kostya})\sqrt d$ and below by $C\sin(\theta_{Kostya})\sqrt d$. So $\theta_\mathrm{MMH}$ can go to zero or to one and we still have a sharp bound, provided the dimension does to infinity fast enough.

Comment: @PierrePC, ouch, thanks! I changed $\theta_{Kostya}$ to $\nu$.

Comment: Just a very small point: $E\|\eta\|$ is asymptotic, but not equal, to $\sqrt d$.

Comment: To elaborate on Iosif's comment, $E\|\eta\|^2=d$, so $E\|\eta\|<\sqrt{d}$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, without a calculation (clearly equality is impossible here), and the exact value could also easily be found (in terms of $\Gamma$ functions) by using the $\chi^2(d)$-distribution.